# Set background of Activity from another one

Tags: android, background, onclick

I'm trying to set a background from ActivityB to AcitivtyA using getInstance but it only show me the Toast message, whenever  turn back to ActivityA, there's no change.

I have this in my ActivityA:

```
private static MainActivity activityA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activityA = this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
    return activityA;
}

public void setLeavesBackground() {
    FrameLayout mainFrameLyt = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainFrameLayout);
    mainFrameLyt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "New style applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And this in my ActivityB:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_style);

    ImageButton leavesBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leavesBtn);

    leavesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.getInstance().setLeavesBackground(); //call myFunction using activityA
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach to get an Instance of another Activity and modify it from within another activity is wrong:

```
public static MainActivity getInstance(){
    return activityA;
}
```

You have to [obey the Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

A way how you could set another activities background is by creating a shared preferences value for the background color and use it in the onCreate method of your Activity.ñ

Comment: with the shared preferences you will also have the advantage that you can persist the user's selection after the app gets closed.